# How to Initialize an Immutable val outside scope of class

Tags: scala, immutability, lazy-initialization

I was wondering if there is a way in scala to define an immutable value without initializing it to any parameters until it is explicitly called with a value to initialize it outside the scope of that class.

**Ex:**

```
abstract sealed class Animal{
  abstract val age:Int
}

case class Dog() extends Animal{
  override lazy val age:Int = _
}
```

Now imagine the **Dog** gets called from outside the bounds of the class, say in a **Main** class as such:

```
object Main extends Main{
val dog = Dog()
dog.age = 12 // HOW CAN I DO THIS -- without defining age as mutable?
}
```

Comment: Clunky, but works: `case class Dog(a: () => Int) { lazy val age = a() }`

Answer (score 4):

The value being immutable means that ... (surprise!) it cannot be mutated. 
You must initialize it when it is created:

```
 case class Dog(age: Int) extends Animal
 val dog = Dog(12)
```

Also note, that (1) case classes without parameters don't make very much sense, and (2) declaring a val in a case class outside of the parameter list doesn't quite work the way that one would expect.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass age as constructor parameter if you define Dog class like below

```scala
abstract sealed class Animal {
  val age:Int
}

case class Dog(val age: Int) extends Animal

object Main extends Main {
  val dog = Dog(12)
}
```